# Count the number of values in each dictionary key including one value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict with 200e3 integer keys that have either one or two values each (strings).

I need to write logic that checks if each key has more than one value, if so add to a list.

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict = {1: ['789456', '456123'], 2: '123456', 3: '987654'}
final = []
```

This is what my initial solution. This works for two values, but returns the length of characters when only one value exists.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        final.append(key)
    else:
        continue
```

I tried enumerate but it only returns the range.

```
for x in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
    print(x)
```

I came up with this solution but I'm not sure if there would be any issues with `defaultdict(list)` being used. Or if there's a larger issue I might not be seeing.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, list):
       final.append(key)
    else:
       continue
```

Comment: Your final code variant seems to do the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Good catch thank you! @jarmod

Comment: Could also rewrite as a one-liner : `final = [k for k,v in my_dict.items() if isinstance(v, list)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```py
final = [k for k,v in my_dict.items() if type(v) == list and len(v) > 1]
```

or in your code:

```py
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    # only this additional condition is present before `and`
    if type(value) == list and len(value) > 1:
        final.append(key)
```

Here, both `'34534'` and `['534', '456465']` are iterables and `len()` function works for both of them hence, we need to check the type of the value and only check length in case of the `list`.

Comment: I suspect that if type is list, it always means more than 1 items, so your code could become even faster, by removing the second condition (len>1)